# The input textarea don't work with mobile on JQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, keyboard, textarea

I use **JQuery mobile** to develop an **Web-App**. On computer **textarea** work fine. When i test on IOS device, i get the popup keyboard but i **can't type anything**.

---

HTML

```
<label for="msg">Observations:</label>
<textarea name="msg" id="obs"></textarea>
```

info :

- JQuery-1.9.1.min.js
- http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js
- http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css

Any help would be greatly appreciated =)

Comment: and some code would be greatly appreciated =)

Comment: I tried code provided with same libraries and it works fine on iOS7, iPad. No problems with typing... It should be something else, like if you set maxlength='0' on text area, or some javascript to prevent typing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

like **@yuriy-kvartsyanyy** said the problem come from something else.
In my case, it's came from css :

**style.css**

```
* {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

**I added this line in my css to solve my problem**

**style.css**

```
textarea {
    -webkit-user-select: auto;
}
```